# Visual Studio Tool for GIT work with Gitblit

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, gitblit

I had success in integrating [Visual Studio Tool for Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions/0?showDiscussionForm=True) to work with Gitblit server.

But I have an error when I push a file:

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).  
   Early EOF
```

Everything seems OK when I check the data on the gitblit server. Nothing is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to work with [gitscc](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/)

It has support for 2008, 2010 and 2012. I use git-scm +gitExtension+Gitblit Server+ gitscc and it works great